# Adding unrelated step to Robot Data Driven test case

Tags: robotframework, data-driven-tests

Consider the following data driven test case:

```
TC001_Sign_in_test
    [Documentation]     testing sign in with various credentials.
    [Teardown]          ${None}
    [Template]          attempt sign in and check status
    ${corr_usrnm}       ${corr_pswd}        ${welcome_screeen}
    ${corr_usrnm}       ${mispld_pswd}      ${sign_in_error_label}
    ${corr_usrnm}       ${EMPTY}            ${sign_in_error_label}
    ${EMPTY}            ${corr_pswd}        ${sign_in_error_label}
    ${mispld_usrnm}     ${corr_pswd}        ${sign_in_error_label}
```

After my first step in the test where we login with correct username and correct password, my app is already signed in and I would like to sign out so I can work on the next incorrect password step.

I was wondering if it was possible to insert a sign out step between the correct password and incorrect password steps. I dont have to do it this way, I could put the successful step in the end and solve the problem easily or just create another separate test for successful login, but I would like to know if it was somehow possible to insert an action in between the two rows of the data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the logout step(s) to your template keyword, `attempt sign in and check status`. If this is a keyword imported from a library you cannot modify for some reason, you can always create a *wrapper* user keyword that calls this keyword and then calls the keyword(s) required to logout

Of course since not all of your tests actually make a successful login, you may have to setup a condition based on the expected status passed to your template keyword.

Comment: That is a good way of doing it, that I had not thought about previously. But does it mean there is no way to add a procedural step inside the data table by using something of the sort of an escape character?